# Как залогиниться на https://steamcommunity.com/ с помощью php?

Tags: php, post, get

Что с помощью снифера и GET/POST запросов это я уже понял. Как передать пароль если он зашифрован?

Comment: Напишите кто нибудь почему у меня всегда -∞.
Если я тормоз и хочу узнать то, чего не знаю. Что в этом плохого?

Comment: вопрос типа вынь-да-полож-мне-влом

Comment: @MikeReacher, просто для начала прочитайте информацию о том, как задавать вопросы на Stack Overflow: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Pyramidhead спасибо за совет, но ничего нового я там не прочитал. Заголовок короткий и понятный по моему, а далее я написал что уже знаю что нужно использовать для решения проблемы, но не знаю как передать пароль, поскольку он зашифрован. Выходит мне нужно тоже зашифровать пароль, но я не знаю как, поэтому и написал вопрос.
Что здесь не так? Если Вам не трудно ответить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steam OpenID](http://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=russian)

Я так понимаю вам нужно смотреть именно в эту сторону. Обучающих видео в интернете полно (и реализаций на PHP).